# Adding a dict to a JSON object as a node in Python?

Tags: python, json

I want to have a data structure that looks like this:

```
{'A':
     {<A-object>:
                 {'B':
                      {<B-object>:
                                  {'C': <C-object>
                                   }
                       }
                  }
      }
}
```

I have a class structure which is as follows:

```
class A(object):
    # code for class A
class B(object):
    # code for class B
class C(object):
    # code for class C
```

I want to be able to have the above structure as a single node within the JSON object that I intend to finally create. However, I am unsure how to initialize the node given the fact that the class instances define my nested levels.

Any help here will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: looks like a good use case for descriptors. Btw, Class A has a b property of Class B right?

Comment: Well i wouldnt call it a property as such, but you can think of it as multiple class B objects constitute a class A object, and multiple class C objects constitute a class B object if that makes sense.